# APIUrl prefix not working with Azure APIM

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I have one AZURE Apim which is mapped to App service where I have deployed web API's(separate API for each customer).
I have added an API URL prefix(Customer Name) in APIM endpoint so that I can define endpoints based on the customer as below.
APIM URL: http://demoapim.com
apim URL prefix : customer name(cust1, cust2)
so now URL would be

http://demoapim.com/cust1
http://demoapim.com/cust2

web API endpoint: http://cutomerapi.com/details

When I am trying to access http://demoapim.com/cust2/details  or http://demoapim.com/cust1/details,
it gives 404.but http://demoapim.com/details works.
Please help me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After understanding apim, I have the following points, I hope it can be helpful to you.**

1. No matter how many apim URL prefixes, cust1, cust2 and so on you have set. The final access address is `/cust1/details`, the route of this address is not recognized in webapp services. So the problem now arises.
2. So I think the problem should not be in apim services, what you should pay attention to is your webapp services. You can rewrite the url or identify cust1 or cust2 for the access request and return the corresponding data.

**URL Rewrite eg.**

Your original URL:
`http://demoapim.com/cust2-details`

Final URL:
`http://demoapim.com?cust=cust2&title=details`

*Using url rewrite in webapp services will better meet your business needs.*

Comment: Thanks jason. I understand your solution but I want cust1 as part of url not as input parameter.http://demoapim.com/cust2/title=details

Comment: @Sachan Of cause you can set it in portal, but it will cost your long time to set it for all apis.

Comment: @Sachan If you have 10 apis in your apps. And you also have 3 customs,I think  you need set 30 times in portal.

Comment: My understanding of apim may not be very deep, if there is a better solution, you can send out the answer, which can help more users.